# JQuery Tags Input Plugin ASP.NET Not Working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc

Im wanting to test this plugin out: http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/ using ASP.NET MVC 5. I've imported the CSS and JS files to correct places and put them in bundles but the code isn't working at all and makes no difference to my TextBoxFor<>

```
@Html.JQueryUI().Tooltip(".tooltip-example-3").Track(true).Hide(Effect.Scale).Show(Effect.Scale)
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="tooltip-example-3">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tags, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
         <div class="tags">
             <div class="col-md-10">
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tags, new {id = "tags_1"})
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tags)
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I've put this JavaScript at top of my page:

```
function onAddTag(tag) {
    alert("Added a tag: " + tag);
}
function onRemoveTag(tag) {
    alert("Removed a tag: " + tag);
}

function onChangeTag(input, tag) {
    alert("Changed a tag: " + tag);
}

$(function () {

    $('#tags_1').tagsInput({ width: 'auto' });
    $('#tags_2').tagsInput({
        width: 'auto',
        onChange: function (elem, elem_tags) {
            var languages = ['php', 'ruby', 'javascript'];
            $('.tag', elem_tags).each(function () {
                if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp('\\b(' + languages.join('|') + ')\\b')) >= 0)
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
            });
        }
    });
    $('#tags_3').tagsInput({
        width: 'auto',

        //autocomplete_url:'test/fake_plaintext_endpoint.html' //jquery.autocomplete (not jquery ui)
        autocomplete_url: 'test/fake_json_endpoint.html' // jquery ui autocomplete requires a json endpoint
    });


    // Uncomment this line to see the callback functions in action
    //          $('input.tags').tagsInput({onAddTag:onAddTag,onRemoveTag:onRemoveTag,onChange: onChangeTag});

    // Uncomment this line to see an input with no interface for adding new tags.
    //          $('input.tags').tagsInput({interactive:false});
});
```

Its not working at all. Any help would be great :)

Comment: Try checking the console if it gives any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what you have to change in you script.

```
function AddTag(tag) {
alert("Added a tag: " + tag);
}
function RemoveTag(tag) {
alert("Removed a tag: " + tag);
}
function onChangeTag(input, tag) {
alert("Changed a tag: " + tag);
}
$('#tags_1').tagsInput({width:'auto',onAddTag:AddTag,onRemoveTag:RemoveTag});
```